# cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'float'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Tags: python

I have here df2, which is a range of values from 1st Jan to 26th Aug. I created a new data frame defining there column, spring summer and Autumn. I want to move values within each range of dates for each season into the appropriate columns in the new dataframe. I got this error and am unsure where to go next. Anyone have any ideas?

```
'print(df2)
seasons = (pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Winter','Spring','Summer', 'Autumn']))
Sp = df2[pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2020', end = '28/02/2020')]
for value in Sp:
    if value >0:
        seasons['Winter'].append(value)'
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the final dataframe to look like?

Comment: I would like the Columns 'Winter', Spring, Summer and Autumn to contain the values which were taken within those seasons. currently df2 is structured in rows  like so..... 2020/01/01       1.5,  2020/01/02          1.2..... on in that fashion until the 26th of August.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when building DataFrames in pandas, you're better off collecting your data in native collections (lists, dicts, tuples), and then turning them into a DataFrame at the end. Adding cells or rows to a DataFrame bit by bit is slow.

The specific error you're getting here is that append only works for combining pandas objects.

You can use `.loc` assignment to do what you're describing, but it's not recommended:

```
for i, value in enumerate(Sp.values):
    seasons.loc[i, 'Winter'] = value
```

But the way you are pulling values makes me think a new table doesn't make the most sense here.

It might be better to add a new column to df2 called Season that labels each row as Winter, Summer, etc based on date. Then you can use `groupby('Season')` or `query('Season == "Winter"')` to pull out the data season by season.

To create the Season column, you just need a function that will tell you what season a row is in. I don't know what's in your table, and I'm not that good with datetime objects, but it would be in this form:

```
def assign_season(index):
    season = ...
    return season
```

Then you create the column with something like:

```
df2['Season'] = [assign_season(x) for x in df.index]
```

You don't have to use the index, you can use a column, but the form is basically the same. Just make sure the function is designed for what you're passing to it. You can also key off multiple column values:

```
def assign_season(val1, val2):
    ...

df2['Season'] = [assign_season(*vals) 
                 for vals in df2[['Column1', 'Column2']].values]
```

Comment: I see, how would I go about doing that? define the column first maybe? like df2['season] = 0, then creating a for loop to assigning a season to each value? I know these may be silly questions I'm very new to Pandas.